# PayPal express checkout displays blank page

Tags: wordpress, paypal

I am using PaidMembershipsPro and I was first doing my website on WAMP server. The payment was using PayPal express and everything worked fine, but when I moved the website onto the server it displays blank page when I click the PayPal checkout button. It works fine with PayPal standard checkout, but not with express.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting a blank page then a PHP error must be happening, but you don't have errors enabled.

[Enable WP_DEBUG](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) in your wp-config.php file.  That will show the errors so you can see the problem and fix it.

Comment: Thanks! it seems that my server didn't have cURL installed, I thought there is a problem with my .htaccess, because I got '/wp-content/plugins/akismet/.htaccess: Require not allowed here' . It only appears for Akismet plugin that I didn't even install, can that be a problem in the future?

Comment: btw. my first 100 reputation! yay! :)